# How to check if multiple conditions strings exist in the csv using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader, equals, contains

I am using `BufferedReader` to check for multiple strings if they exist within a file and i am using the below script:

```
int n = 41; // The line number
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(context.tfilelistdir)); 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    line = br.readLine();
    if (line.contains("$$WORDS$$ ABC") && line.contains("$$WORDS$$ XYZ"))
    {
        do something
    }
}
```

Here I need to check if the string `$$WORDS$$ ABC` **and also** `$$WORDS$$ XYZ` both exist in different rows/cols within the csv file. BufferedReader's line does not accept `&&`. It only works with `||` (OR) condition BufferedReader overwrites the entries as it keeps reading the records.

Any way to check if both condition exist (strings exist) within the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the substrings are in *different* lines, some boolean flags need to be introduced to track each specific condition.

Also, it's better to use `try-with-resources` to ensure the file/reader resources are closed properly, and check if the file end is not reached in the reading process (then `br.readLine()` returns `null`).

```java
int n = 41; // The line number
String line;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(context.tfilelistdir))) {
    boolean foundABC = false;
    boolean foundXYZ = false;
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i++ < n) { // read at most n lines

        foundABC |= line.contains("$$WORDS$$ ABC"); // will be true as soon as ABC detected
        foundXYZ |= line.contains("$$WORDS$$ XYZ"); // will be true as soon as XYZ detected
        if (foundABC && foundXYZ) { // not necessarily in the same line
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution,its perfect -really appreciate it.I have a small tweak since i would want to print only the line(lines) where there is a match and not print everything inside the if loop-how can i do that,since i am using while its printing all the lines with output like
if (foundABC && foundXYZ)
     {
   System.out.println("MATCH 1 FOUND");
   //System.out.println(line);
       }

Comment: Case 2:i would also need to check different conditions by using if loop ,like if different other lines are having a match with different condition,so i have written it like:
  foundABC |= line.startsWith("$$WORDS$$ 9");
  foundXYZ |= line.contains("COND=Test"); 
  else        if (foundABC && foundXYZ)
     {
   System.out.println("MATCH 2 FOUND");
   //System.out.println(line);
       }
similarly i need to check for various conditions /matches based on the boolean flag it has to go within that if-nested loop and print only that specific line having a match
is the code accurate ?

Comment: 1. You could reset the flags as soon as both patterns are found, or add flags inside loop and check if the conditions are true also for current line: `boolean currFoundABC = line.contains("$$WORDS$$ ABC");  boolean currFoundXYZ = line.contains("$$WORDS$$ XYZ"); foundABC |= currFoundABC; foundXYZ |= currFoundXYZ; if (foundABC && foundXYZ && (currFoundABC || currFoundXYZ)) {/* match found */}`

Comment: Thanks i will try that,One final thing how do i use bufferedreader.readLines() and capture the value from the csv file.
There are many rows within the file and there would be one row namely 
$$NAME$$ TOM,i need to find or match the identifier name and capture the value after the $$ and store TOM within a string variable to process...
i ask coz i am hardcoding the values to check in the IF-condition for the current requirement,but for getting the name ,i need to find the value and store it.Thanks in advance,really awesome

Comment: Possibly the last thing would require to search for a pattern using regular expression but this seems to be a bit too much for questions in the comments  :)  Also, for case 2, additional clarifications would be needed and especially input data, expected outputs and actual outputs.  Please do not hesitate to post a new question at SO when you have one, and do not forget to accept/upvote useful answers.

Comment: Thanks alex  appreciate your help,i created a separate thread to extract the values from the fields since here we just spoke about if condition to check if the value exists only.Please take a look when you get a chance and share your feedback
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033185/how-to-capture-the-field-values-in-the-csv-file-using-bufferedreader

Comment: i have a small query ,got one condition wherein if one of the column  line starts with $$PHONE$$ 9 and has another column where COND=x then the value of a string string name="tom"
Else if column begins with $$PHONE$$9 and does NOT have a line where it reads COND=X ,then string name="james"

Comment: boolean curroper9= line.startsWith("$$PHONE$$ 9");
   oper9 |= curroper9;
  
  boolean currcondmicro=line.contains("COND=X"); 
  condmicro |= currcondmicro;

    boolean currcondnotmicro=!line.contains("COND=Microsite"); 
  condnotmicro |= !currcondnotmicro;
  

 else   if (curroper9 && currcondmicro &&  (  curroper9 || condmicro) )
     {
     System.out.println("NAME IS TOM");
       }
else if  (curroper9 && currcondnotmicro && ( curroper9 || currcondnotmicro)   )
{
     System.out.println("NAME IS JAMES");
       }
it wont print just one line of output ,and result is wrong

Comment: can you please help how i can match precisely the condition and make sure its right