# How to capture the field values in the csv file using bufferedreader

Tags: java, regex, string, csv, talend

The csv file looks like this [image]

[image]

I'm trying to get the field values like name, it is the value after $$NAME$$ (there is a space after the identifier). How do I store the value for each field by using BufferedReader in Java? The fields could be in any line number and not in a fixed place or format, and also throw out an error if there is any special characters or null value is encountered.

```
      int n = 100; // Max lines
              String line;
              try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str)))
               {
                   while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i++ < n)
                {
                      br.readLine();
                  line = br.readLine();
                  System.out.println(line);
                 }
               }
```

Once the values are extracted from the CSV file, I need to store them in a string variable and use it later to insert into the database for each column values

Case 2:And also for the last field $$GROUP$$ CATEGORY the value is "5" in cell 9 to 11 and i need to match that the column CATEGORY in the database has to be 5 stored in a string to be inserted into the database column of the same name.
The regex wont find the exact match when i used line.matches condition

Comment: Why do you need to determine _Max lines_ ? Do the fields repeat, i.e. does `$$NAME$$` appear more than once? Does each line consist of only what you wrote in your sample or are there other values in each line of the file? Is there also a space in the file after `$$WEATHER$$` ? How do you want to store the field values? Do you want to store them in some data structure like `ArrayList` or write them to another file or insert them into a database?

Comment: The fields dont repeat,i mentioned max lines just because i dont want to iterate through all the lines in the csv coz i believe the required fields must be at the top no later than first 100 lines .Each line has only the values i mentioned, yes there is a space after $$WEATHER$$(space) ,i prefer to store the extracted values in a string to insert as column values into a database table

Answer (score 1):

The following code will read only the first 100 lines of the file and extract the values into a list.

```java
java.nio.file.Path path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(str);
try {
    java.util.List<String> values = java.nio.file.Files.lines(path)
                                                       .limit(100)
                                                       .filter(line -> line.matches("\\$\\$[A-Z]+\\$\\$ [0-9A-Z]*$"))
                                                       .map(line -> {
                                                           String[] words = line.split(" ");
                                                           return words.length == 2 ? words[1] : "";
                                                       })
                                                       .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(values);
}
catch (java.io.IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```

According to the sample file in your question, the above code will create the following list.

```
[JOHN, CA, SF, XYZ, , 25, CATEGORY, ]
```

If you want a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of a `List` where the `Map` key is the value between the double `$` characters and the `Map` value is the part after the space, then

```java
Function<String, String> keyMapper = line -> {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    return parts[0].substring(2, parts[0].length() - 2);
};
Function<String, String> valueMapper = line -> {
    String[] parts = line.split(" ");
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        return parts[1];
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
};
Path path = Paths.get(str);
try {
    Map<String, String> map = Files.lines(path)
                                   .limit(100)
                                   .filter(line -> line.matches("\\$\\$[A-Z]+\\$\\$ [0-9A-Z]*$"))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper));
    System.out.println(map);
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will create the following `Map`

```
{GROUP=CATEGORY, WEATHER=, CITY=SF, STATE=CA, TIME=, NAME=JOHN, REGION=XYZ, AGE=25}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex here to both detect the name line:

```java
int n = 100; // Max lines
String line;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i++ < n) {
        if (line.matches("\\$\\$NAME\\$\|$.$")) {
            System.out.println(line.split(" ")[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it wont match and is not going inside the if loop (regex) to match and extract the values
if (line.contains("\\$\\$NAME\\$\\$.$"))
{
            System.out.println(line.split(" ")[1]);
}
I tried using line.contains still it wont match the csv field called $$NAME$$ ...There is a space after the last $ ,inspite of that too using .(matches 0 or more chars) it wont pickup the value?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first split the line by space, then you'll have something like
$$NAME$$, JOHN. Then retrieve the key between the dollar signs.

An example based on your snippet:

```
int i = 0;
int n = 100; // Max lines
String line;
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str))) {
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && i++ < n) {
    String[] splitLine = line.split(" ");
    String key = splitLine[0].split("\\$\\$")[1];
    String value = splitLine[1];
    System.out.printf("Name: %s | Value: %s%n", key, value);
  }
}
```

You could also use a more modern approach using Java 9 Files API and streams, here's an example of that:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    Path filePathFromProjectFolder = Path.of(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("file.csv").toURI());
    Map<String, String> csvValues = Files.readAllLines(filePathFromProjectFolder).stream()
        .map(line -> line.split(" "))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(line -> getKeyName(line[0]), line -> line[1]));

    System.out.println(csvValues);
  }


  private static String getKeyName(String str) {
    return str.split("\\$\\$")[1];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract data from a CSV file according to the format of “fieldname field value”. The code will be rather long if you try to do this in Java.

Try using SPL, the open-source Java package, to get it done. It is easy with only two lines of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =file("data.csv").read@n().select(left(~,2)=="").(right( ,−2).split("") |
| 2 | =create(${A1.(~(1)).concat@c()}).record(A1.(~(2))) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as csv2tbl.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…
Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");
con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");
st = con.prepareCall("call csv2tbl()");
st.execute();
…
```